# I want to create a auto generated code for product based on product name text box value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a ASP.NET MVC project. In my form, I have Id,Product Name,Code. Code will be Auto generated based on Product Name. How to do that using J Query.  I am a Beginner and i am facing problem with this. Any Suggestions? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48787116/edit) your question to show the [code you have so far](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/). You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help. You should also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: how do I do what, exactly? "based on product name" is not a sufficient requirement. How does the derivation take place? Give examples? And also show what you tried so far - this isn't a free coding service. You can learn how to get a string using JavaScript/jQuery and presumably how to read it and how to make a new string, and how to take parts from the original string, if necessary. All these are common tasks. Try something and ask about your actual code if you get stuck.

Comment: Sorry, bro, I will keep this in mind.    Now I have done that.                                    @section Scripts
{
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".txtCountryName").blur(function () {
                var value = $(this).val();
                var newValue = value.substring(0, 3);
                $('.txtCode').val(newValue);
            });
        });
    </script>
    
}

Comment: Ok, so please edit that into your question so it's readable, and also what goes wrong with your code? What does it do now? What did you expect it to do? Give a real example if it helps. And also show the HTML which goes with it, thanks. We need enough info to be able to run your code.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to generate a random value for code field, and I have done that like this.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

        $(".txtCountryName").blur(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            var ram = Math.random().toFixed(2) * 100;
            var newValue = value.substring(0, 3);
            $('.txtCode').val(newValue + ram);
        });
    });
</script>
```